# How to get the exact first date and time of last month?

Tags: java, datetime

I wish to get the exact date of first day of last month at `00:00:00Z`.
So, here is my current solution:

```java
public static String getStartingDateAndTimeOfLastMonth() {
    int dayOfCurrentMonth = ZonedDateTime.now().getDayOfMonth();
    return ZonedDateTime.now()
                        .minusDays(dayOfCurrentMonth - 1)
                        .minusMonths(1)
                        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
}
```

When i call the moethod:

```java
String startDate = CustomUtilsFunctions.getStartingDateAndTimeOfLastMonth();
System.out.println("startDate: " + startDate);
```

The output of current solution is:

```
startDate: 2021-05-01T07:22:10.389Z
```

As you can see, the time of the output is `07:22:10.389Z` but, I don't know the easiest way to turn it to `00:00:00:000Z`

So the desired output for is:

```
startDate: 2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Point:
I know, i can extract the **hour**, **minutes** and **seconds** and **millis** and then use the `minus()`, but I believe there must be an easier solution.

Comment: You could try `truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)` and maybe prepend `withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using *today* as base, you could use a `java.time.YearMonth` (like *this month*) and subtract one month to get the last one. Then take the start of its first day. Do all that in UTC and then format as desired:

```java
public static String getStartingDateAndTimeOfLastMonth() {
    // get the current month and subtract one to get the last
    YearMonth lastMonth = YearMonth.now().minusMonths(1);
    // then return its first day
    return lastMonth.atDay(1)                
                    // at the beginning of the day in UTC
                    .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                    // formatted as desired
                    .format(
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                            "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX",
                            Locale.ENGLISH
                        )
                    );
}
```

This outputs today (10th of June, 2021):

```
2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

**Note:** The default format of `ZonedDateTime` omits seconds and fraction-of-second if they are zero.
If you are fine with `2021-05-01T00:00Z`, you can replace

```java
    .format(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX",
            Locale.ENGLISH
        )
    );
```

with simply `.toString();`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks for your edit, I just realigned the indentation for better visibility. I missed the correct format ;-), good to have more eyes watching answers here!

Answer (score 5):

You could first create the desired day and then use it together with a set time to compose `DateTime`. Depending on your use case, you could use `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`.

```
LocalDate day = LocalDate.now()
        .minusMonths(1)
        .withDayOfMonth(1);

ZonedDateTime target = ZonedDateTime.of(day, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, ZoneId.systemDefault());

System.out.println(target);
```

Another option would be to use `turncatedTo` (as @Thomas mentioned in comment)

```
ZonedDateTime target = ZonedDateTime.now()
        .minusMonths(1)
        .withDayOfMonth(1)
        .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
        .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("UTC")); // optional depending on your case
```