# How to format Date string to date and time using ZonedDateTime?

Tags: java, datetime

I have string like **"2021-06-01"** and i wish to convert it to the **"2021-06-01T00:00:00+02:00"**.
I know that, the easiest solution is concatanation of string:

```
date = date+"T00:00:00+02:00";
```

However, i wish to do it using `ZonedDateTime`. Currently my solution is:

```
  public static String formatDate(String date, DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(date).format(formatter);
  }
```

and then call this method with:

```
formatDate('2021-06-01', DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

However, it complains with :

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-06-01' could not be parsed at index 10
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Do you always want `+02:00` on the end? Or should that be the system's local offset or something like that?

Comment: Yes, it should always be `02:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to always have an offset of `+02:00` hours, a `ZonedDateTime` will not be a good choice because it will consider daylight saving time.

Here's a demo that shows why you might want to use an `OffsetDateTime`:

Assume you have two methods:

```java
public static String formatDate(String date, int offset) {
    return LocalDate.parse(date)
                    .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.ofHours(offset))
                    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
}
```

and

```java
public static String formatDate(String date, String zone) {
    return LocalDate.parse(date)
                    .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of(zone))
                    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
}
```

Both of them take a `String` just like your example `"2021-06-01"`. The second argument is an offset in the first method and a zone name in the second.

Using both methods with the same date as `String` but different second arguments, like this

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateOne = "2021-06-11";
    String dateTwo = "2019-11-19";
    String dateThree = "1998-03-27";
    
    String zone = "Europe/Paris";
    int offsetHours = 2;
    
    System.out.println(formatDate(dateOne, offsetHours));
    System.out.println(formatDate(dateOne, zone));
    System.out.println(formatDate(dateTwo, offsetHours));
    System.out.println(formatDate(dateTwo, zone));
    System.out.println(formatDate(dateThree, offsetHours));
    System.out.println(formatDate(dateThree, zone));
}
```

will produce this output

```
2021-06-11T00:00:00+02:00
2021-06-11T00:00:00+02:00
2019-11-19T00:00:00+02:00
2019-11-19T00:00:00+01:00
1998-03-27T00:00:00+02:00
1998-03-27T00:00:00+01:00
```

As you can see, there are differences due to daylight saving time.
That means your requirement *it should always be `02:00`* given in a comment below your question will not reliably met if you use a `ZonedDateTime` (in a way it should be used).

Please note that both example methods use a `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` which produces a `String` in your desired format. You can safely use it with a `ZonedDateTime` while you cannot do it the other way round, that would mean formatting an `OffsetDateTime` with a `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME` because an `OffsetDateTime` does not have information about a zone. A `ZonedDateTime` does and, thus, always has information about the (zone-specific) offset.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks... I think the three answers together (so far) should provide enough information here.

Comment: Thanks. It was great, as i learned something important.

Answer (score 3):

## [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-)

> However, i wish to do it using ZonedDateTime.

It is similar (not exact) to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67916622/10819573).

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getOffsetDateTime("2021-06-01"));
    }

    public static OffsetDateTime getOffsetDateTime(String strDate) {
        return LocalDate.parse(strDate)
                .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.of("+02:00"))
                .toOffsetDateTime();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-01T00:00+02:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/iifPQh)

If seconds and fraction-of-second are zero, they omitted by default (i.e. from `OffsetDateTime#toString`). If you want to retain them, you can use `DateTimeFormatter` e.g.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getOffsetDateTime("2021-06-01"));
        System.out.println(getFormattedOffsetDateTime(getOffsetDateTime("2021-06-01")));
    }

    public static OffsetDateTime getOffsetDateTime(String strDate) {
        return LocalDate.parse(strDate)
                .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.of("+02:00"))
                .toOffsetDateTime();
    }

    public static String getFormattedOffsetDateTime(OffsetDateTime odt) {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH).format(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-01T00:00+02:00
2021-06-01T00:00:00+02:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/DTfFIX)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

Your date string does not have a time, and does not have a zone, so it can't be parsed to a `ZonedDateTime`. You are also using the wrong `DateTimeFormatter` to format it. `ISO_LOCAL_DATE` produces the format `yyyy-MM-dd`, not the one you want.

You should instead parse the date string to a `LocalDate`, which is *just a date*, because there's only that much information in that string.

Then, you should add the time component and the offset component to the parsed date, *then* format it:

```
public static String formatDate(String date) {
    return LocalDate.parse(date)
        .atStartOfDay() // sets the time to 00:00:00
        .atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(2)) // sets the offset to +02:00
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME); // formats it using the desired format
}
```

Note that `atOffset` gives you an `OffsetDateTime`, which is enough for what you want to do. If you really want to use `ZonedDateTime`, just change it to `atZone`, and it will work too, but I think it's unnecessary.